# Text after .php/ in a URL

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm basically trying to reverse-engineer a site made in Wordpress. My peer made our site in wordpress, and I would like to add some code to processing data from a form using the Contact Form 7 plugin. When viewing source, the form action is

```
/v2/wp/index.php/contact-us/#wpcf7-f57-p9-o1
```

Also I noticed that all the URL's of the various pages have text after the .php, which I don't understand.

```
http://.../index.php/information-for-sponsors/
```

In the first case, I don't understand how the "/contact-us/..." is processed. In the second case, I don't understand how "/information-for-sponsors/" is processed.

Comment: That's either read as "`PATH_INFO`" or rewritten into a query string parameter through a `RewriteRule` commonly.

Comment: as @mario said it could be RewriteRule. Check for `.htaccess` file in your project directory that is used for RewriteRule

Comment: if you mean `#wpcf7-f57-p9-o1` part, it does nothing but scrolling to the form when the page is reloaded. As far I remember, wpcf7 uses ajax to submit the form. Look in the console and network tab for clue.

Comment: It seems to me that you should **hit some books** before going any further. The web is not trivial and WordPress is far from trivial. Your understanding of both seems a little light for the job you have taken on.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this you need to look down the mod_rewrite option for Apache. It allows you to map urls and can be combined with php to get what you need.

For instance, I write a blog software before which translated the url .com/contact/ to .com/index.php?key=contact

Then using the key in php I returned the post with the title contact.

Google Apache Mod_ReWrite, it takes a while to undertstand fully and you need this option enabled on your host. Many Free hosts dont have this functionality enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Though all the comments and answers above are absolutely correct, I am not sure, however, if you will understand any of them correctly.

Well, this concept is called **URL Rewriting** and is used for a variety of purposes such as improving ranking in search results, making readable keywords,etc.

There are lots of plugins in Wordpress which do this dirty work for you and there is also the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)(if you wish to write your own).

For your reference, I found this blog which will explain this better.
[Smashing Magazine Article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)